# Mongoose, does this model already exist in the collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose on a Node.js server to save data into MongoDB. What I want to do is to check and see if a model object exists in the collection already.

For example heres my model:

```
var ApiRequest = new Schema({
    route: String,
    priority: String,
    maxResponseAge: String,
    status: String,
    request: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

And here's what I would like to do:

```
var Request = mongoose.model('api-request', ApiRequest);

function newRequest(req, type) {
    return new Request({
        'route' : req.route.path,
        'priority' : req.body.priority,
        'maxResponseAge' : req.body.maxResponseAge,
        'request' : getRequestByType(req, type)
    });
}

function main(req, type, callback) {
    var tempReq = newRequest(req, type);

    Request.findOne(tempReq, '', function (err, foundRequest) {
        // Bla bla whatever
        callback(err, foundRequest);
    });
}
```

The big issues I'm finding are that the tempReq which is a model has an _id variable and a timestamp that is going to be different from what is saved in the database. So I would like to ignore those fields and compare by everything else.

As a note my actual models have more variables than this hence the reason I don't want to use .find({ param : val, ....})..... and instead would like to use the existing model for comparison.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use plain JS objects instead of Mongoose model instances as query objects (the first parameter to `find`).

So either:

Change `newRequest` to return a plain object and later pass that into a `new Request()` call if you need to add it to the database.

OR

In your `main` function turn `tempReq` into a query object like this:

```js
var query = tempReq.toObject();
delete query._id;
Request.findOne(query, ...
```